# Setting ListGrid selection in SmartGWT

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

I'm trying to set the selected records of a ListGrid table object in SmartGWT, but I can't find any way of doing it. I know there's a getSelectedRecords() function, but no matching setSelectedRecords(). I tried to see if set/getSelectedState() would work, but GWT complains about needing a primary key and a DataSource object. Is there any way to set the selection of a ListGrid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this you can use one of the [`selectRecords()`](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/index.html?) methods, like so:

```
public void onModuleLoad() 
{
    VLayout main = new VLayout();
    final ListGrid grid = new ListGrid();
    grid.setHeight(500);
    grid.setWidth(400);
    grid.setFields(new ListGridField("name", "Name"));
    grid.setData(createRecords());

    final IButton button = new IButton("Select some");  
    button.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {  
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) 
        {  
          grid.selectRecords(new int[]{2, 3}); //This will select index 2 and 3
        }  
    });  

    main.addMember(grid);
    main.addMember(button);
    RootPanel.get().add(main);
}

private ListGridRecord[] createRecords() 
{
    return new ListGridRecord[]{
      createRecord("monkey"),
      createRecord("banana"),
      createRecord("orange"),
      createRecord("sun")
    };
}

private ListGridRecord createRecord(String name) 
{
    ListGridRecord record = new ListGridRecord();
    record.setAttribute("name", name);
    return record;
}
```

Comment: Ugh. Why does it seem like they are hiding functions from me? Thanks.

Comment: @therin I know the feeling, these interfaces are really bloated and inconsistent. Glad I could help.